# How can I add a text from a list to open a file?

Tags: python, list, text

I'd like to open a file but I don't want to write the name of the file everytime, that's why I want to create a list and then choose the element by putting 0,1,2...
I don't understand how it works, I tried to do this but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me ?

```
L=["file1","file2","file3"]

file = open('D:/folder/'L[0]'.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: For starters, don't open the file for *reading*.

Comment: Refer to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: You want to see an open text file have text entered into programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your looking for here is string formatting or f-strings.

Assuming you'd like to read information from a file with the path `D:/folder/file1.txt'` you should use f strings to format the correct path as such:

```
file = open(f'D:/folder/{L[0]}.txt', 'r')
```

You can use this idea to iterate through your list and read the individual files and do what you need to do with it:

```
for filename in L:
    file = open(f'D:/folder/{filename}.txt', 'r')
    # Do operations for each file here
```